# Share office scripts connected to Excel with external organisations

Tags: excel, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I have developed a tool in Excel that is based on Office scripts. The tool is developed for external organisations.

Unfortunately, office scripts attached to an Excel workbook can only be shared within your own organisation. External organisation do not have access to the office scripts.

To solve this issue, I was planning on publishing the office scripts within a Teams sharepoint with all the participants added to it. However, I discovered that office scripts saved to a sharepoint can not make fetch calls to the internet. The tool developed needs to be connected to the internet, so this option seems infeasible.

Are there any other ways/workarounds to share the Excel tool and its office scripts with external organisations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the Office Scripts team at Microsoft and thank you for bringing this to our attention! Currently there is not a way to share Office Scripts with external organizations other than copy/pasting code. We are currently investigating into how we can support sharing scripts across tenants.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will copy/pasting code for now then. I hope this functionality will be added soon!

Comment: Will scripts saved to sharepoint be able to access the internet in the near future? Is this something that is being worked on?